# How to add a form in my .jsp file to send the values in the URL as pathvariabls not params . like this :- http://localhost:9091/getFeedback/138

Tags: forms, spring-boot, jsp, input

I want to extract in my Controller.java this way (@PathVariable Integer id):-

```
// Get /http://localhost:9091/getFeedback/138
@GetMapping("/getFeedback/{id}")
public Feedback getFeedback(@PathVariable Integer id) {
    return service.getFeedback(id);
}
```

Not this way:-

```
@GetMapping("/getFeedback")
public Feedback getFeedback(@RequestParam Integer id) {
    return service.getFeedback(id);
}
```

I tried :

```
<form method="Get" action="getFeedback/">
      ID: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onsubmit`:

```html
    <form
      method="Get"
      action="getFeedback/"
      onsubmit="this.action = this.action + this.name.value; this.submit();"
    >
      ID: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```